# MSVC LINK cannot open library if called by python script

Tags: python, visual-c++

I have a python script that automatically compiles and link c/c++ files in a project.
It works fine on gcc/linux(WSL) but on MSVC/Widows the linking stage fails.

```sh
LINK /VERBOSE /MACHINE:X64 /OUT:bin/Game.exe /LIBPATH:ext/raylib/lib/debug/ objs/srcbattling.obj objs/srccamera.obj objs/srcgraphics.obj objs/srcmain.obj objs/srcmapLoader.obj objs/srcmeshUtils.obj objs/srcutils.obj "gdi32.lib" "raylib.lib" "user32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "opengl32.lib" "winmm.lib" "shell32.lib"
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Starting pass 1
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '"gdi32.lib"'
```

It always fails to find the first library listed, whatever it is.

But if i copy paste the command on the shell manually it works without problems.

I use subprocess.Popen to execute commands

```python
stream = subprocess.Popen(command.split(" "), stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Everything is run on the MSVC x64 dev shell

Somebody knows where the problems stands?

Comment: My guess would be, in the shell you have `LIB` environment variable  defined that provides a path to `gdi32.lib`, but when running from your script you don't. Either define the environment variable, or pass all the necessary directories via `/LIBPATH` option.

Comment: I used `set` to check any difference in environment variables. The libpath (and everything else) is the same via both cmd and Popen

Comment: Ah, I think I know. You pass `"gdi32.lib"` to `Popen`, including quotes; those are passed as is to the application (Popen will escape them if necessary). Whereas when you run the same command in the shell, quotes are stripped by the shell, and what reaches the application is `gdi32.lib`, without quotes. Note how the error message says `cannot open file '"gdi32.lib"'`, citing the file name in quotes. That's literally the file name it tries to locate.

Comment: My God I feel so stupid, you are correct, the problem are the double quotes. I added them tring to fix another problem. Thanks